# Image grid as button in bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 images with different sizes. I want to create a grid of 2x2 with each block is equal to each other and it is a clickable image (work as a button). How can I do this in CSS/Bootstrap?

This is what I have tried (in Rails):

```
<div class="row row-cols-2 main-wrapper px-4">
      <%= link_to students_path, class:"nav-link col btn btn-light center-div" do %>
        <%= image_tag "/assets/bg/cs-ds-bg.jpeg" %>
        <p class="h2">Student stories & Research</p>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to faculties_path, class:"nav-link col btn btn-light center-div" do %>
        <%= image_tag "/assets/bg/cs-bg.jpeg" %>
        <p class="h2">Faculty & Staff</p>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to courses_path, class:"nav-link col btn btn-light center-div" do %>
        <p class="h2">Courses</p>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to requirements_path, class: "nav-link col btn btn-light center-div" do %>
        <p class="h2">Computer Science & Data Science <br>
          Major & Minor Requirements</p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-wrapper {
    height: 80vh;
}

.center-div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 0.5px solid #000000;
}
```

[This is the image of what it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDC9P.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? This is not a "we code it for you" service. Please post the code you already have and where you are stuck with it.

Comment: share the html code of what have you tried so far.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]